# How can I check if turtlebot3 bump an obstacle?

Tags: ros-melodic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In turtlebot2, I see it is based on the research robot, iClebo Kobuki, so it can subscribe to a bumper event 'mobile_base/events/bumper', how to do it in turtlebot3?

Thank you so much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344398/how-can-i-check-if-turtlebot3-bump-an-obstacle?/) by [HaiSanCamRanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/51553/haisancamranh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot3 does not have any bumpers, so the first thing you need to do would be to physically add those in some way, then hook them up to spare inputs on the openCR board, read them and publish the state of them to that topic

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HaiSanCamRanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/51553/haisancamranh/) on 2020-02-18**:
thank you a lot